# How to remove an element from an IGrouping

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

How do I remove an object directly from an IGrouping `IGrouping<DateTime, VMAppointment>`?

The only way I know of currently is to generate a new IGrouping without the concering element, but I don't like this way because it causes some trouble within my application.

Any ideas?

Comment: "it causes some trouble within my application" is very vague. Please be more specific in your questions - see http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, there's no way to mutate an `IGrouping<,>`, at least in general - and even if you knew the concrete type, I don't believe any of the implementations exposed by the .NET framework allow the group to be mutated.

Presumably the grouping is the result of some query - so if possible, change the original query to exclude the values you aren't interested in.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is old question, but hopefully this helps someone else.  A workaround for this is to cast the group to a list, then use the values from the list instead of the group.

```
var groups = someList.GroupBy(x => x...);

foreach (var group in groups)
{
    var groupList = group.ToList();

   ...

    groupList.Remove(someItem);

    //Process the other code from groupList.
}
```

Comment: Surely this wouldn't remove the item from 'someList' though? Only from the newly generated list within the foreach.

Answer (score 2):

You could cast using `Select` and use `TakeWhile` if you have a testable condition (such as null as in the example) on a property in your group:

```
var removedItemsList = group.Select(x => x.TakeWhile(t => t.someProperty != null));
```

This will return an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<YourGroup>>`.