# How to filter the elements of an IEnumerable of IGrouping by keeping the IGroupings

Tags: c#, linq

I have a sequence of `IGrouping`s

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<Key, Element>> sequence = ...;
```

and a predicate

```
Func<Element, bool> predicate = ...;
```

How can I filter the `Element`s by keeping the result an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<Key, Element>>` without flattening the sequence and recreating completely recreating the groupings?

I could do something like

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<Key, Element>> filtered =
    from grouping in sequence
    from element in grouping
    where predicate(element)
    select new { grouping.Key, element } into keyElem
    group keyElem.element by keyElem.Key into g
    select g;
```

but that, depending on the size of sequence and on the types involved, would take some time and/or memory.

I would like to "simply" filter the elements inside the `IGrouping`s. I'd accept empty groupings in the result.

(I think that this question can be answered by answering the question how to filter the elements of an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Element>>` while keeping the result an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Element>>`.)

Comment: What if one of the groups becomes empty due to the filter; should the empty group be removed from the sequence, or should it be kept in?

Comment: Well it's easy enough to do it to yield a result of `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Element>>`, but I'm not sure this really helps you: `var result = sequence.Select(subsequence => subsequence.Where(element => element == "X"));`, for example.

Comment: @RuudHelderman thanks, edited.

Comment: Couldn't you modify the predicate to `Func<IGrouping<Key, Element>>` and use it like `sequence.Where(predicate)` which produces desired `IEnumerable<IGrouping<Key, Element>>` result instead, or this is not an option?

Comment: @MichalŠuvada How to create such a predicate? That’s basically my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't modify an existing `IGrouping`, but you could easily creating your own implementation and a helper method:

```
public static class Groupings
{
    public static IGrouping<TKey, TElement>
        FilterElements<TKey, TElement>(
        this IGrouping<TKey, TElement> grouping,
        Func<TElement, bool> predicate) =>
        new LateGrouping<TKey, TElement>(grouping.Key, grouping.Where(predicate));
}

internal class LateGrouping<TKey, TElement> : IGrouping<TKey, TElement>
{
    public TKey Key { get; }
    private readonly IEnumerable<TElement> elements;

    public LateGrouping(TKey key, IEnumerable<TElement> elements)
    {
        Key = key;
        this.elements = elements;
    }

    public IEnumerator<TElement> GetEnumerator() => elements.GetEnumerator();

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}
```

Then you can just take your `IEnumerable<IGrouping<...>>` and use a normal select, filtering on the inside:

```
groupings = groupings.Select(g => g.FilterElements(predicate));
```

Comment: Hi, you need to add <TKey, TElement> also to the name of function FilterElements, in other way it won't even compile. So it should look like this: public static IGrouping<TKey, TElement> FilterElements<TKey, TElement>(...)

Comment: @Marcin: Done. (That would have been fine as a direct edit though.)

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to remove an item from an `IGrouping` which is essential for this idea ([How to remove an element from an IGrouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12163855/how-to-remove-an-element-from-an-igrouping)).

The most beautiful way would be to remove Enities and remove empty IGroupings after this:

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, object>> sequence = null;
Func<object, bool> predicate = null;
// Would be nice if this would work
//Parallel.ForEach(sequence, y => y.Remove(y.Where(z => predicate(z))); });
sequence = sequence.Where(s => s.Count() == 0);
```

So we need to form a new object for every `IGrouping`

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, object>> sequence = null;
Func<object, bool> predicate = null;

IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, object>> result2 = sequence.Select(s =>
{
    var t = new MyGrouping<string, object>() { Key = s.Key };
    t.AddRange(s.Where(w => predicate(w)));
    return t;
}).Where(s => s.Count > 0);
```

But you'll need this class:

```
public class MyGrouping<TKey, TElement> : List<TElement>, IGrouping<TKey, TElement>
{
    public TKey Key
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

I do like the easy one:

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, object>> sequence = null;
Func<object, bool> predicate = null;

// Make it a List again
var tmpList = sequence.SelectMany(s => s.ToList().Select(l => new { key = s.Key, val = l }));
// Filter your List
var tmpFilteredList = tmpList.Where(l => predicate(l.val));
// Group it back again
IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, object>> result = tmpFilteredList.GroupBy(g => g.key, g => g.val);
```